# Deploying my first asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, hosting

novice here reading the ins and outs of deploying my project to a live server. I've got an unfinished project that is basically just going to be a cms for a portfolio. The code can be found here:
https://github.com/LewisGoldstone/Portfolio

I'm avoiding azure as after the first month it seems way too expensive for something this small scale. I'm lost with what I really need to be looking for as I can't seem to tell apart the cheap from the very expensive. Here's a few I've been looking at that seem reasonably priced and seem well reviewed (I'm based in the UK, not sure if that makes a difference):
https://hostinguk.net/ 
aspnethosting 
asphostportal 
tsohost

Any plans you would recommend?

Are cloud servers worth it?

Also is IIS 8 a must with my project (it's been built within vs 2015 community)?

Comment: Azure can get you 10 sites for free. Depending on what all you need, that may be plenty. Of course, if you do get into areas where you need paid features, then a more traditional hosting service often winds up being cheaper unless you need to scale out. Anyways though, asking for us to reccomend a hosting service isn't on topic. Please see [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sorry, could've sworn I'd seen similar topics with recommendations going back in forth. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't mention any specific vendors but I would suggest looking for hosting that provides the following:

- Support for WebDeploy deployments
- Support for newer versions of IIS    (at least 7)
- Early support for
  ASP.NET Core (indicates they are    looking ahead)
- A nice dashboard for remote management
- Remote debugging with Visual Studio

Comment: That's great help. Much appreciated

Comment: If you like this answer please don't forget to mark it as the answer to your question and vote it up.